# What is Object Eclipsing?

Tags: oop

This is a question my interviewer asked me.
My Answer is -

if we assign an object of the derived class to 
the reference of the base class , the members of the derived class will eclipse or hide.

he didn't tell it's wrong or right.
I want to confirm it.

Comment: I cannot find anything on this so it looks to me like it's a bogus term and either he didn't know what he was talking about or he meant something different, maybe EclipseLink (which would sound similar) as a persistance framework.

Comment: The correct response was "I'm afraid I haven't actually heard of that specific term before..."

The brave response would be "a trick question..."

Comment: Maybe he was thinking of "shadowing": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept "object eclipsing".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the interviewer meant to say *[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)*?

That, or it was a trick question.